# Associate between server response and view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am a beginner developer in Objective-C/iOS and I have this simple question.

My program interact with a server side and I use `GCDAsyncSocket` for asynchronous communication.

I wonder, suppose the use is opening my status view controller which causes a request for server, but before the response arrives he has already moved to a different view!

What is the right way the handle this situation??

Thank you!

Comment: You question is a bit confusing! - please rephrase 'I wonder, suppose the use is opening my status view controller which causes a request for server, BUT before the response arrives he has already moved to a different view!'

Comment: Can you callback not check to ensure that it's still showing the view for which the request originated?

Comment: Yeah, that's is probably what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not move to the next view controller until you get the response in didReceiveData callback, because your GCDAsyncSocket delegate will have to be set to some controller, and probably you would have by default set it to the status view controller.

So you have to wait for the callBack response and upon receiving it you can move to the next view controller.

While the delegate can be set to the next view controller, you can skip it for now as you a beginner in iOS.

Comment: Preventing user from switching to different view, is that the common solution for such a case?? I thought about it but couldn't decide for myself...:-)  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is key.

> asynchronous

You're using an asynchronous request to get your data.  You'll have to use callbacks to let the view controllers know that the request has ended.  I've never used that library but a quick glance at the readme says:

```
Classic delegate-style support.
All of the following result in calls to your delegate method: connections, accepts, read     completions, write completions, progress,
```

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/README.markdown
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Reference_GCDAsyncSocket

Comment: I understand that I need callback, but the question was how to associate the response to the correct view?!? or maybe like Prem Kumar suggested - prevent from switching to a different view until response arrives.